# React stateless component + children with typescript : error Property 'children' is missing in type 'IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: reactjs, types, typescript, compiler-errors

I have two simple stateless react components (presentational) :

```
const MsgDisplay = ({msg}) => (
  <div>
    {msg} // will be more complicated later
  </div>)

const RowDisplay = ({data, children}) => (
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>{ children }</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>)
```

When I try to use them from the container component :

```
public render() {
    return (
      <RowDisplay data={this.props.xyz} >
        <MsgDisplay msg={someMsg} />
      </RowDisplay>
    )
  }
```

typescript (1.8.7) complains that : `error TS2324: Property 'children' is missing in type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { data: any; children: any; }'.`

It seems it can't see I'm passing the children props in jsx notation.

Of course I could use explicit `children={}` on `RowDisplay` but that's ugly...

I can I prevent typescript from complaining ?

Comment: Opened a typescript bug : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8588

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39908701/2877817