# Property is missing in type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having an issue with working through a demo React project. Most of the issues stem from me trying to implement it in Typescript where they are using Javascript. This gist is my app.tsx file.

https://gist.github.com/jjuel/59eed01cccca0a7b4f486181f2a14c6c

When I run this I get errors pertaining to the interface.

> ERROR in ./app/app.tsx
>   (38,17): error TS2324: Property 'humans' is missing in type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & AppProps & { children?: ReactElement |...'.
>
> ERROR in ./app/app.tsx
>   (38,17): error TS2324: Property 'stores' is missing in type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & AppProps & { children?: ReactElement |...'.
>   webpack: bundle is now VALID.

I have no idea what is going on with this. Does anyone know what my issue could be? Thanks!

Comment: 404 Page not found... So this question is useless.

Comment: 404 Page not found in the original code :(

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You have the following interface :

```
interface AppProps {
    humans: any;
    stores: any;
}
```

Which is you saying that `App` must be passed in `humans` and `stores`. However you are initializing it as `<App />` in `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('main'));` **without the properties**. This is TypeScript providing you with errors about what you said was the *intented* use. It's an error like having a function with arguments but calling it without passing any.

## Fix

Perhaps these properties are *optional* for you? If so declare it as such:

```
interface AppProps {
    humans?: any;
    stores?: any;
}
```

Otherwise provide them e.g. `<App humans={123} stores={123} />` (sample instances of humans and stores).

Comment: The problem with making the arguments optional is that in the render method that uses the props you get an error that the argument is possibly undefined. As pointed out it is a bit like calling a function without arguments. But with a function the default arguments are used. For React it seems in the render method the defaultProps is not taken into account?